# ViewPager refuses to show its pretty little head

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm unable to get a ViewPager nor its contents to appear. What am I missing?  I've included two versions of the XML layout below.  Version#1 includes the ViewPager.  Version#2 excludes the ViewPager so you can see there is content that should be visible within the ViewPager.  Your thoughts would be appreciated on how to resolve this.

Edit--the adapter code is now included.  It's worth noting that the ViewPager content is not visible *even in Eclipse*.  I.e., I believe the adapter is independent of the problem.

```
    class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
        return guideContainer.getChildAt(position); 
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return timeSlotContainersHD.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
    }

     @Override public void destroyItem(View arg0, int position, Object arg2)  {  
     } 
}
```

Version #1 including ViewPager:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/GuideSideScrollView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/Green"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center"
    android:background="@color/Orange"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MiddleView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".05"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="ViewPager Below Me"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/Orange" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/GuideViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/TimeSlots1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/FirstButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button2"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/TimeSlots2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@color/Green"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/FirstButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button3"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button4"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TimeSlot1Program2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/Charcoal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="ViewPager Above Me"
        android:textColor="@color/Orange" />
   </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

[image: Screenshot of version#1]

Version #2 excluding ViewPager:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center"
    android:background="@color/Orange"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MiddleView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".05"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="NO ViewPager Below Me"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/Orange" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/TimeSlots1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/FirstButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button2"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/TimeSlots2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@color/Green"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/FirstButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button3"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button4"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TimeSlot1Program2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/Charcoal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="NO ViewPager Above Me"
        android:textColor="@color/Orange" />
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

[image: Content visible when ViewPager removed]

Comment: Show us the adapter you use to power the ViewPager.

Comment: I added the adapter code.  It's worth noting that the ViewPager content is not visible even in Eclipse.  I.e., I believe the adapter is independent of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a while but I've now resolved this issue by inverting the hierarchy of the layout.  Instead of putting the ViewPager inside the ScrollView, I'm now programmatically building an array of ScrollViews.  Each ScrollView is at the top level of the individual ViewPager pages.  Everything is now working great.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are trying to define the layout of your ViewPager inside the  `<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>` element, if I get that right.

Don't do that. Instead, define a seperate layout XML for the Fragments you will use. Then you load it in your Fragments programmatically.

You can see an example of how to do it here:
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/android-tutorial-using-the-viewpager.html

Try:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center"
    android:background="@color/Orange"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MiddleView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".05"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="ViewPager Below Me"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/Orange" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/GuideViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TimeSlot1Program2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/Charcoal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="ViewPager Above Me"
        android:textColor="@color/Orange" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

And see what it shows.

Comment: Hi Terry, I should have mentioned that the actual app *does* programmatically create the LinearLayouts that populate the ViewPager.  That is not working either though.  for testing purposes I then tried the static implementation which I described here.  both approaches produce the same (lack of) result.  Help!

Comment: I edited the answer to contain the layout XML how I mean it. Tell me if it shows something.